# .js Script works in HTML, but not Razor .CSHTML (MVC)

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I downloaded this number pad from the internet, since I'm not prolific in javascript, and implementing it in HTML. When testing it in HTML it worked no problem, but when importing the code to a Razor .cshtml file the script stopped working.

I got the numpad from here: https://code-boxx.com/pure-javascript-numeric-keypad/

I made a few modifications, but nothing directly to the .js file, changed the path since it was on a different folder, and the script tag looks the same on both (they're copy pasted)

The page also got slightly unformatted from the CSS that I wrote, but I'm blaming that on Razor weirdness and will fix it later, maybe it has something to do with something.

Here's the whole thing (.cshtml) without css.

```
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Views/Home/JSNumpad/numpad.css" />
    <script src="~/Views/Home/JSNumpad/numpad.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <div class="division">
            <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        </div>
        <div class="division">

            <br>
            <input type="number" id="input" name="input">
            <label for="input">Kgs</label>
        </div>
        <div class="division">
            <div id="button-container">
                <button class="button" id="button1">1</button>
                <button class="button">2</button>

            </div>
            <div id="extra-input">
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Dinheiro</label>
                    <input type="number" id="dinheiro" name="dinheiro">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Multibanco</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Multibanco" name="Multibanco">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Visa</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Visa" name="Visa">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Outros</label>
                    <input type="number" id="outros" name="outros">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Fundo Caixa</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Fundo" name="Fundo">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Despesas</label>
                    <input type="number" id="Despesas" name="Despesas">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Depósito LIDL</label>
                    <input type="number" id="LIDL" name="LIDL">
                </div>
                <br />
                <div id="button-container">
                    <button class="submitbutton"> Submit </button>
                    <button class="submitbutton"> Cancel </button>

                </div>

            </div>
            <div id="button-container">
                <button class="button">Button 3</button>
                <button class="button">Button 4</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        const button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
        const extraInput = document.getElementById('extra-input');

        button1.addEventListener('click', () => {
            extraInput.style.display = extraInput.style.display === 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        window.addEventListener("load", () => {
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("dinheiro") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("Multibanco") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("Visa") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("outros") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("Fundo") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("Despesas") });
            numpad.attach({ target: document.getElementById("LIDL") });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried different ways to write out the path, since it seems to be a bit strict with that, I tried just the file name, from Home, with the tilde, without the tilde, didn't change anything.